# Infragistics UltraListView auto scroll

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, infragistics

Does anyone knows how to make the Infragistics UltraListView control scrolls down automatically whenever a new item is added?

Comment: This is not really a programming question, more of a support question for Infragistics support team.

Comment: If questions about whether or not you need to know c before programming in C# are okay on here, and get a dozen + votes, I think a question asking about how to do something with a specific control is okay. Besides, their support site sucks. :)

Comment: As shown in the accepted answer, it was a programming question (an issue solvable by code)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
UltraListViewItem i = listView.Items[listView.Items.Count - 1];    
ISelectionManager selectionManager = listView as Infragistics.Win.ISelectionManager;    
selectionManager.SelectItem(i, true);    
i.Activate();
```

Answer (score 3):

UltraListViewItem has BringIntoView() method, which would do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

For a simple scroll down, use the PerformAction method. There are a variety of Infragistics constants that can be used as the argument... intellisense gives good info on this:

(VB)

```
    UltraListView1.PerformAction(UltraWinListView.UltraListViewAction.ScrollVerticalBySmallIncrement)
```

And yes, it's a programming question. ;)